# PHP how to spilt two array

Tags: php

I have an array which is like:

```
array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(3) "1,2" }
```

I want to print them as:

```
 array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "107"},array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "2"}
```

Here is my code:

`$a = explode(",",$row['z']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to print it like...

```
array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "1"}
array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "3"}
```

...

then that should work.

```
$rowSplitted = array();
$zValues = explode(',', $row['z'])
$yValue = $row['y']
foreach ($zValues as $zValue) {
    $rowSplitted[] = array(
        'y' => $yValue,
        'z' => $zValue,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = array("y"=>"A","z"=>"1,2"}
$zArrayFromCSV = explode(",",$row['z']);
$newArray = array();
foreach ($zArrayFromCSV as $valueZ) {
    $newArray[] = array("y"=>$row['y'],"z"=>$valueZ);
}
var_dump($newArray);
//array(2)
//{
//  [0]=>array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "1"}
//  [1]=>array(2) { ["y"]=> string(1) "A" ["z"]=> string(1) "2"}
//}
```